# driver.close not working in testng

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

Hi when i am running my test through a plan java code and use WebDriver's close() method it is closing respective browser instance. But when i am using the driver.close() in a testNG class inside any of the @After annotations like

```
@AfterClass
public void logout()
{
driver.findElement(By.id(someSignOutId)).click();
driver.close();
}
```

then it is not closing the browser instance. 
Please try below 2 code snippets :
TestNGSnippet :

```
package unitTest.myTest;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class GoogleTestNGTest {
  @Test
  public void f() throws InterruptedException 
  {
      WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.close();
  }
}
```

Plain Snippet:

```
package unitTest.myTest;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class GoogleTest 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 
    {
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

Is it a bug in testNG. NOTE: driver.quit() is working, but i cannot use it as when i am running my tests in parallel then it will close all my browser instances on which tests are still running. TIA!
Selenium WebDriver version : 2.33
TestNG : 6.8.5
Firefox version : 22
Java : 1.7.0.40

Comment: Mrunal please add the stacktrace of any error if any. Also, are you using afterclass as well as @Test or just @Test?

Comment: Your problem is that your @Afterclass is not in your class (or in the class that the test class extends).

Comment: Hi All you can simple copy paste my above code snippets and try it at your side and you will come to know my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi all as of now i have found out a workaround to close the driver from testNG. See below my workaround :

```
package unitTest.myTest;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class GoogleTestNGTest {
  @Test
  public void f() throws InterruptedException 
  {
      WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.googl.com");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.close();
try
{
driver.get("someURL");
}
catch(UnreachableBrowserException e){}
}
```

I found out that the browser session has already expired. but it is just that the browser window that has not got closed. so when we again try to it the same driver instance with some url. it closes out the browser. I hope this workaround helps for other users facing similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

It is *not* a bug in TestNG.

If anything, it is a bug in Selenium.  Remember that `driver.close()` will close the active window...meaning if a test has multiple windows opening, you will need to close all of them.

You said that you are running multiple tests in parallel...I hope that that you are using multiple driver instances....not all of them running on the same driver.  If that is the case, then you *can* call `driver.quit()`, as it will only quit the current instance.

However, if you have managed to have multiple windows on a single driver running different code...then I can't help you, except to recommend to switch to multiple instances (which is much stabler).

Comment: i am running on multiple driver instances not on same instance. And one thing to note is when i am using driver.close() in a single plain java file it is able to close the browser but when i am using it in testNG it is not closing. that is my concern.

Comment: Then use `driver.quit();` If it is not doing what is expected, then take a look at your code.  TestNG does *nothing* with webdriver.  It is completely separate.

Comment: The fact that driver.close is closing the window means it is not a bug with selenium as well.  There is something wrong with the code to consume it.

Comment: @niharika_neo i agree with you that there is nothing wrong with selenium, but probably there is something wrong with testNG. Try my above two code snippets as it is and you can re-create the issue.

Comment: Mrunal, if that is your code...then it's simple. The @Afterclass method is not in the class.

Comment: @MrTi i am referring to TestNGSnippet and PlainSnippet code and not to the one with AfterClass.

Answer (score 0):

This workaround is fine, but anyone in here can explain why this functionality is not working? All my @AfterSuite @BeforeSuite and @Test are in the same class. But still driver.close is not working whereas driver.quit works, but driver.quit closes all browsers, so wanted to use only driver.close which is not closing the browser.

Comment: first of all this is not an answer so if you want to post a comment post in comment section. i would like to know which version of selenium are you using? i believe this is now not an issue in the latest selenium version.

Comment: @Mrunal, I was unable to post in comment section, so entered my inputs in Answer section. And for your question, i am using 2.42 and FF 31.

Comment: i have tried with 2.42.2 and FF 28 it is working now. you too try and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

`Driver.close`, sometime doesn't work as soon as you navigate to a new page.

So solution is to wait for page to load (either use `Thread.sleep` ) or increase default timeout.
After that try `driver.close()`, it will work.